# can not shutdown or restart or even hibernate again after hibernate (ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: hibernate, restart, shutdown, ubuntu-18.04

I have a almost the problem match to this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/936442/ubuntu-hibernate-works-just-one-time#)
but In addition to the hibernate again i dont able shutdown or restart my laptop.

i have a ram with 8GB size and my swap partition is 11.2 GB

help me please !

i think that is about swap . because at the first i don't have swap partition ( i have a swap file ) and i set it . after that i configure grub for mount swap partition at boot . 
any thing else need ?

`Edit`
Result of 'journalctl -f'

```
 nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to idle channel 0 [DRM]
 kernel: pci_pm_freeze(): nouveau_pmops_freeze+0x0/0x20 [nouveau] 
 returns -16
 dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_freeze+0x0/0xe0 returns -16
 kernel: PM: Device 0000:01:00.0 failed to freeze async: error -16
```

`Edit`

`systemctl hibernate` or `pm-hibernate` have same problem 
but `s2disk` show saving progress and it be 100% and then hibernate but when resume . doesn't resume current state !